# How to Communicate between Qt and a HTML page in QTWidget Application

Tags: html, qt

I am trying to find a way to connect a button in HTML to an action in my C++/Qt application. I loaded a HTML file in QT app using QTextBrowser object. If I click a button in this HTML file, the Qt application should respond. I also might want to implement it vice versa: so that an action in the Qt application would cause a response in the HTML page. Please suggest a suitable solution.

My sample code is :

```
QWebView view;
view.setStyleSheet(
  "background-color:rgb(150,147,88); padding: 7px ; color:rgb(255,255,255)");
view.load(QUrl("test.html"));
view.show();
```

is there any mechanism like signal/slot ??

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do this, as your sample is working with *QWebView* rather than *QTextBrowser*, I'll assume your working with the *QWebView*.

For page to application [`QWebView::linkClicked(const QUrl& url)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#linkClicked) signal is fired when a link is clicked, and `QWebView::load(const QUrl& url)` will change the page.

If you are creating a JavaScript application, have a look at the [QtWebKit Bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) documentation. This allows two way communication with JavaScript running on a page.